# How can I compile a Direct3D 9 effect from a file?

Tags: c++, shaders, directx

I started working with shaders recently in DirectX9. I noticed that there is a `D3DXCompileShaderFromFile` function for `IDirect3DVertexShader9` and pixel shader. Which compiles the shader and gives you the compiled code so you can put that into a file and then read it.

But is there a way to do it with the ID3DXEffect or is `IDirect3DVertexShader9` the only way?

Comment: Take a look at [D3DXCreateEffectFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172768(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`D3DXCreateEffectFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

The parameter list is a bit daunting, but most of the parameters are optional and can support null values. Do note, however, the comment for the `flags` parameter:

> If pSrcFile contains a text effect, flags can be a combination of
>   D3DXSHADER Flags and D3DXFX flags; otherwise, pSrcFile contains a
>   binary effect and the only flags honored are D3DXFX flags. The
>   Direct3D 10 HLSL compiler is now the default. See Effect-Compiler Tool
>   for details.

Typical usage would be:

```
LPD3DXEFFECT effect = nullptr;
LPD3DXBUFFER errors = nullptr;
HRESULT result = D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(
  direct3DDevice,
  "Path/To/Your/Effect.fx",
  nullptr,
  nullptr,
  0,
  nullptr,
  &effect,
  &errors
)
```

If the `HRESULT` isn't successful, compilation errors can be recovered from the `errors` buffer (it's just a string; you can case the `void *` returned from [`GetBufferPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205754%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I currently use this function to create the effects. Just to make sure I've got everything right. If I compile the effect with the Effect-Compiler tool and then try to load it with this function it will work fine correct?

Comment: The function supports binary effects, yes. Although not all the flags are supported (it's covered in the docs).

Comment: Note you can actually use [D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx) directly and not use D3DX at all to compile. Of course, if you are using the FX9 framework, you have to use D3DX9.